# Rails radar/forem forum engine - controlling access to certain forums or topics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, forem

I'm using [forem](https://github.com/radar/forem) as forum engine and have it attached to my User model.

As part of my User model, I have "experts" and "novices" as the two different types of users.

If I only want to show the "expert" forum to "expert" users, what is the best way to control this access within forem?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to modify the view under `app/views/forem/forums/_forum.html.erb`, enclosing all with this:

```
<% if forem_user.expert? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Note: if you don't have the forem views, you have to generate them with `rails g forem:views`.

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

The last version of Forem allows to redefine methods for permissions in your User model.

https://github.com/radar/forem/wiki/Authorization-System

So, in your case, you'd define the method `can_read_forem_forum?(forum)` and return `true` if the user is expert.